# A Node.js app runs in a single process, without creating a new thread for every request. Can anyone explain this sentence please?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I'm a beginner and i can't understand this statement. If nodes.js app runs in a single process, does it mean node.js app run faster as compared with multi-process app? What should I conclude?
thank you so much.

Comment: single threaded as in the code u run is all on 1 process.. so blocking is very possible, for example let's say for some reason u have a while loop running waiting for something to happen.. the entire program would get blocked until the while loop is resolved.. but if you have the while loop in a different process(check [child process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)), the original program won't get blocked by the loop

Comment: It's mean in node.js multiple code blocks runs in parallel but packed in a single thread?

Comment: `There is also a very well known and criticized issue with the one thread per request model for a server which is that they don’t scale very well for several scenarios compared to the event loop thread model, in short, they lack scalability as the application grows to meet the future demands and with the addition of new features` according to [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/why-node-js-is-a-single-threaded-language/) so yea single thread does help in speed

Comment: Helpful mate....Thank you  so much.

Comment: idk if that was sarcasm but you're welcome